# Sending a void* from one dll to another dll in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, marshalling

I'm having an application where I need to transfer the value of a `void*` parameter (obtained from one dll) to another dll using a c# application. Below are the function definitions:

DLL 1 Function:
    `int Init(void** BusHandle);`

DLL 2 Function:
    `int AttachHandle(void* BusHandle)`

I made the folowing definitions in c#:

```
[DllImport("1.dll")]
public static extern int Init(ref IntPtr BusHandle); // ref or out seems to to the job in the same way

[DllImport("2.dll")]
public static extern int AttachHandle( IntPtr BusHandle);
```

Running in a ANSI C based application everything works fine, but in a C# application it does not work, it seems that the handle can not be accesed.

Usefull information:

- I do not have the source code of the dlls.
- The Bushandle obtained from the Init function is valid in C# (i have other functions from DLL 1 that use it and it works)
- The handle is refering to a serial port (COM)
- Both DLLs are built under an ANSI C compiler exporting the functions by __declspec(dllexport)
- I am using Visual Studio 2012 with 3.5 Framework

Comment: `int Init(void** BusHandle)` uses a pointer to a pointer, while `int AttachHandle(void* BusHandle)` uses only a pointer - is this correct?

Comment: The only thing obviously out of whack is that your C# declaration doesn't use the CallingConvention property.  It should be Cdecl if you copy/pasted the function declaration properly.  Ignoring the return value of Init() is a pretty standard crime.

Comment: The function declarations are correct. I also tried  specifing the calling convention(cdecl or stdcall) without any success.I corrected the typo regarding return value.

Comment: Just a guess: Please check what platform you are using in your C# project, and for which platform the DLL is compiled. If the DLL is 'x86' then you have to you use 'x86' in your C# project as well (instead of 'Any CPU')

Comment: Tried also the X86 compiler option still no change, I even tried using unsafe code to replace the IntPtr with void*, the same result. I have no idea what else I could try...